# How to change file permissions using the Boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, permissions, boost-filesystem

How can I use the Boost library to change the permissions of a file to read-only?

There are some questions that I have already seen, such as [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#last_write_time) and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#symlink_perms), but I still don't know how to do it, I have tried doing

```
boost::filesystem::wpath path = L"abc.txt";
if( boost::filesystem::exists( path ) && boost::filesystem::is_regular_file( path ) )
{
    boost::filesystem::file_status s = boost::filesystem::status( path );
    /* here I need to set file permissitons to READ ONLY for `path` file */
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, what are the questions? What have you tried?

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
  using namespace boost::filesystem;
  wpath path = L"abc.txt";
  permissions(path, others_read|owner_read);
}
```

Comment: I'm using boost 1.44 and there is no `permissions` in `boost::filesystem` namespace...

Comment: @mosg Well, the links you provided pointed to the docs from 1.49. If you use earlier version, you most likely can't set permissions. Note however that 1.44 is ~3 years old...

Comment: Yes, It's my fault, didn't mentioned boost version. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7):

With boost 1.55, under Windows, the following works:

```
permissions(file_path, add_perms|owner_write|group_write|others_write);
```