# How to change permission on windows by boost library?

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I am on a windows 10 pc and use boost library 1.74.0. I want to change the file permission.

I've seen questions like

[How to change file permissions using the Boost library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810982/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-the-boost-library)

However, when I run the code

`boost::filesystem::permissions(file_path, bf::add_perms | bf::owner_write | bf::group_write | bf::others_write)`

, nothing happened...

So here is my question:

Is it possible to change the permission on windows using boost library ? or using win32 api is the only feasible way ?

Comment: it will mostly depend on the filesystem - you're using a POSIX interface. Windows does support it, but on e.g. NTFS I imagine windows ACLs override it.